# AUC unexpected value

Tags: r, roc, auc

I have the following predictions after running a logistic regression model on a set of molecules we suppose that are predictive of tumors versus normals.

```
                  Predicted   class     
                      T        N          
                 T   29        5
  Actual class
                 N   993      912
```

I have a list of scores that range from predictions <0 (negative numbers) to predictions >0 (positive numbers). Then I have another column in my `data.frame` that indicated the labels (1== tumours and 0==normals) as predicted from the model. I tried to calculate the ROC using the `library(ROC)` in the following way:

```
 pred = prediction(prediction, labels)     
 roc = performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")   
 plot(roc, lwd=2, colorize=TRUE)
```

Using:

```
       roc_full_data <- roc(labels, prediction)
       rounded_scores <- round(prediction, digits=1)
       roc_rounded <- roc(labels, prediction)
```

Call:

```
       roc.default(response = labels, predictor = prediction)
       Data: prediction in 917 controls (category 0) < 1022 cases (category1).
       Area under the curve: 1
```

The AUC is equal to 1. I'm not sure that I run all correctly or probably I'm doing something wrong in the interpretation of my results because it is quite rare that the AUC is equal to 1.

Comment: What exactly did you feed to these functions? A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be very helpful.

Comment: Maybe you need gto do something like `auc(roc(pred, labels))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your x.measure which should have thrown an error. You have "for" and not "fpr". Try the following code.

```
performance(pred, measure = "tpr", x.measure = "fpr")
plot(perf)

# add a reference line to the graph
abline(a = 0, b = 1, lwd = 2, lty = 2)

# calculate AUC
perf.auc <- performance(pred, measure = "auc")
str(perf.auc)
as.numeric(perf.auc@y.values)
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake during copy and paste from my code to here but the original was fpr.

Answer (score 0):

I use `pROC` to calculate AUC:

```
require(pROC)
set.seed(1)
pred = runif(100)
y = factor(sample(0:1, 100, TRUE))
auc = as.numeric(roc(response = y, predictor = pred)$auc)
print(auc) # 0.5430757
```

Or

```
require(AUC)
auc = AUC::auc(AUC::roc(pred, y))
print(auc) # 0.4569243
```

<strike>I can't explain why the results are different.</strike>

EDIT: The above aucs sum to 1.0, so one of the libs automatically 'inverted' the predictions.

Comment: They are the same, but one inverted the prediction. Pure chance will give an AUC of 0.5, so everything less than that is better taken the opposite.

Comment: @Jasper You're right, completely forgot about that!